# Каретка в конец строки

Tags: c#, консоль

Создаю файл через `File.WriteAllText`
Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии файла каретка была в конце файла?

Comment: Чтобы дописывать что-то? Выполнять Append (`File.AppendText`)

Comment: Что означает «при открытии»? Вы имеете в виду, открытие Блокнотом, как в вашем предыдущем вопросе?

Comment: @VladD Блокнотом

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, вы не можете заставить блокнот просто так перейти в нужную позицию. У него нет этого в ключах командной строки, и в текстовом формате такого тоже нет.

Но вы можете сэмулировать нажатие клавиш на клавиатуре, которое отправит каретку в конец файла.

Для этого подключите System.Windows.Forms, и делайте так:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, text);
// запустить процесс
var p = Process.Start("notepad.exe", path);
// дождаться, пока он загрузит документ и начнёт реагировать на клавиатуру
p.WaitForInputIdle();
// послать нажатие Ctrl-End
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^{END}");
// дождаться, пока юзер закроет блокнот
p.WaitForExit();
```